# What is meaning of field item_type_gl_account.direction in moqui?

Tags: moqui

When I query

```sql
select * from item_type_gl_account;
```

What is meaning of field `item_type_gl_account.direction` in moqui?

What is the meaning of `O`, `I`, `E` in `item_type_gl_account.direction`?

[image]

Please guide me the logic of value `I`, `O`, `E` in later accounting posting process logic steps.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the invoices.

`I` is for Purchase Invoices (**I**nward)

`O` is for Sales Invoices (**O**utward).

`E` is for **e**ither of the above.